# reading in 2 txt files to pandas- why is my second file not showing up?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file

I have 2 datasets of the same length I am trying to read in with pandas that are located in the same path with different names- lets say 'path/data1' and 'path/data2'.

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('path/data1' names = ['data1'])
d2 = pd.read_csv('path/data2' names = ['data2'])
data = pd.concat([d1, d2],axis=1) 
data
```

for some reason- the d2 dataframe displays the same information as the d1 dataframe. so I have a 2 of the same columns.
Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is here. Are you saying that the dataframe stored in `d2` is the same as that in `d1` despite `data1.csv` and `data2.csv` having different contents? Also please format your code correctly because as it stands the code you have detailed will not run. For example, the first line should be `d1 = pd.read_csv('path/data1.csv', names = ['data1'])`.

Comment: yes @thornejosh

Comment: data1 and data2 are set to the text files so it runs - it just isn't displaying the correct contents

Comment: Are you sure your code is as above and your files are indeed different? You should not be encountering this issue if that is so. If your files have the `txt` extension you will encounter problems. As you are using `pd.read_csv`, please ensure your files have a `csv` extension.

Comment: yes I have checked to be sure the files are different!

Comment: You will need to convert your `txt` files to `csv`. Please see: https://support.geekseller.com/knowledgebase/convert-txt-file-csv/